# get keys of map without know its

Tags: c++, c++11

My `ObjClass * obj` has a `map<std::string, OtherClass*> obj2`, I want to get all the keys because I want to iterate on the obj2's content.

I can't know a priori what the string contains, so I tried in this way, but doesn't work.

```
    typedef std::map<std::string, ObjClass2*>::iterator it_type;    
    for(it_type iterator = obj.begin(); iterator != obj.end(); iterator++)
    {
        std::cout<<iterator->first<<std::endl;

    }
```

Maybe can I use an further integer index? But how?

Comment: define "doesn't work". be explicit.

Comment: Why do you need all the keys? Can you show some code showing this? You don't need the keys for iterating over `obj2`.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the code below, you need to iterate through obj2 elements:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, ObjClass2*>::iterator it_type;    
for(it_type iterator = obj->obj2.begin(); iterator != obj->obj2.end(); ++iterator)
{
    std::cout<<iterator->first<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: I got this error: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘obj’, which is of pointer type ‘ObjClass *’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
I tried so to change with the '->' operator but I got another error that say to me that ObjClass hasn't member 'begin' and 'end'.

Comment: @user2369478 obj->obj2.begin() means that your need firstly access obj2 member of obj and then invoke begin/end that belong to obj2, not to obj

Comment: Oh, sorry. I wanted to say "request for member ‘begin’ in ‘obj2’"

Comment: @user2369478 could you please provide me with the ObjClass declaration?

Answer (score 2):

If you say that obj has type `ObjClass *` then it is obvious that this construction

```
it_type iterator = obj.begin();
```

is invalid.

If you need to get all keys of obj2 you can write for example the following way

```
for ( const auto &p : obj->obj2 )
{
   std::cout << p.first << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @user2369478 I do not know what code you are testing. The code I showed is correct.

Comment: @@user2369478  Maybe the problem in your phrase "My ObjClass * obj has a map<std::string, OtherClass*> obj2". I do not understand it, It is class ObjeClass that as I guess contains the map, not ObjClass *